# $user argument with filter login_redirect still return null

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

```
function admin_default_page($user) {
    $url_home = get_site_url();
    global $user;
     // die(var_dump($user));
     $roles = $user->roles;
    if($role != 'subscriber'){
        // exit( wp_redirect(home_url()));
         return $url_home.'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page';
    }else{
        return $url_home;
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page',10,3);
```

$user still return null
wordpress's codex talk about 3 arguments
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/

If i put this 3 arguments i have php error :"Too few arguments to function admin_default_page()"

Slowly by slowly it's better but....
I have to add that

```
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');
function do_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
}
```

Then $user->roles still return null so wordpress redirect to

```
$url_home.'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page'
```

and not just to

```
$url_home
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are comparing role with undefined variable $role I think it should be roles.
second you have not defined the number of parameters in add_filter
Try below it should work

```
function admin_default_page($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
    $url_home = get_site_url();
    global $user;
     // die(var_dump($user));
    if(!in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles )){
         return $url_home.'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page';
    }else{
        return $url_home;
    }
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Slowly by slow it's better but....
I have to add that 
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');
function do_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
}
Then $user->role still return null so wordpress redirect to $url_home.'/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page' and not to just $url_home

Comment: use $user = wp_get_current_user(); to get current user object then use $user->roles to get the user roles.
You want it to run on init hook ?
earlier you asked for login redirect

Comment: i'tried wp_get_current_user() but same problem. Sure i want to redirect subscriber role to home url if this role want to use the login form at www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin

Comment: The code which i shared will definitely work. what issue you are getting in that ? else you can try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: i'am sure this code works, evreybody use that. But i can't explain why $user->role still return null. my problem is here.

Comment: you are writing it as role or roles?
it should be roles ( "$user->roles" )

Comment: can you please send me the error? where you are checking the value ? please send the screenshot

Comment: There isn't any error when I do die(var_dump($user)); $user return null :
C:\wamp64\www\mysite\wp-content\mu-plugins\custom-role.php:439:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: ohk, so you are creating a plugin? direct adding code in functions.php will work right?

Comment: Yes, but the same problem in function.php of the theme

Comment: On login page ?

Comment: I don't have login page, the people connect with default wordpress login page. You talk about login.php ? for the test only ?

Comment: wp-login.php is fine. I can't tell now unless I do practically on your code because the code should work & even I tested at my end. It will show null before login but the code will work after login.